# WinAPI create window with standard behavior

Tags: winapi

This question is a result of a discussion. I was wondering if a window that is created via WinAPI can behave like explorer windows e.g. can be controlled by the Windows and the arrow keys. (if you press Windows + ArrowKey the focused window should move and snap in that direction on the side).

Is it possible to tell that a window should behave like this or would one have to handle such control commands by himself?

Comment: What did your CreateWindowEx experiment show?

Comment: It's not possible to *tell* a window to implement standard behavior. It simply does. It is possible to change that behavior, though.

Comment: The shell treats every toplevel window with a sizable border this way.  It is not implemented by the window itself.

Comment: Your question is answered in [Handling AeroSnap message in WndProc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321549/handling-aerosnap-message-in-wndproc), found through "winapi aero snap". :-)

Answer (score 1):

All "standard" behavior is provided by `DefWindowProc`.  As long as you pass all unhandled messages to `DefWindowProc`, you'll get it.