# How to block resizing after a double-click on a dialog window's top or bottom edges in Windows 10?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, win32gui

I'm coding a customized popup window with C++ using Win32. The condition for this popup window is that it can be only resized from the bottom down. The following is the implementation of such restriction:

```
RECT rcInitialWindowRectangle = {0};

//The dialog has WS_THICKFRAME style

LRESULT CALLBACK DlgWndProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            //Set minimum window size
            ::GetWindowRect(hDlg, &rcInitialWindowRectangle);
        }
        break;

    case WM_SIZING:
        {
            //Restrict sizing on all sides but bottom
            if(wParam != WMSZ_BOTTOM)
            {
                RECT* pRcWnd = (RECT*)lParam;

                //Preserve all sides but bottom
                int b = pRcWnd->bottom;
                *pRcWnd = rcInitialWindowRectangle;
                pRcWnd->bottom = b;

                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
        {
            //The following is needed to restrict minimum window size
            int w = rcInitialWindowRectangle.right - rcInitialWindowRectangle.left;
            if(w != 0)
            {
                MINMAXINFO* pMMI = (MINMAXINFO*)lParam;

                pMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = w;
                pMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = rcInitialWindowRectangle.bottom - rcInitialWindowRectangle.top;

                pMMI->ptMaxTrackSize.x = w;
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        {
            //The following is needed to display correct cursor for resizing
            POINT pnt = {GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam)};

            RECT rcWnd;
            ::GetWindowRect(hDlg, &rcWnd);

            //L, T, R, B
            RECT rcBtm = {rcInitialWindowRectangle.left, 
                rcWnd.bottom - 16,  //Some arbitrary border 
                rcInitialWindowRectangle.right,
                rcWnd.bottom};

            return ::PtInRect(&rcBtm, pnt) ? HTNOWHERE : HTBORDER;
        }
        break;


    return 0;
}
```

So this works except one thing. On Windows 10, there's evidently a new feature -- when someone double-clicks on the bottom (or top) edge of a window -- here's an example with Notepad so that you can try:

[image]

that window is resized (stretched) to the top and bottom of the screen (akin to maximization, but only vertically.)

So my question is how do I block this double-click resizing? (In my case the top of the popup window should not move.)

PS. My first instinct was to block all double-clicks on the window's edge, but then I thought that maybe there's a *less barbaric* way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you made a window with `WS_SIZEBOX` style? If you have custom requirements on sizing behavior it might be a good idea to manage resizing manually.

Comment: For some reason the AeroSnap stuff in Windows was kludged in at a lower level than normal window resizing and there's no public API for any of it.

Comment: Also FWIW, the feature you are trying to defeat is not new in Windows 10, it works in 8.1 as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt wow, I must really be distracted today. I'll delete my comments.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Nope. Doesn't work in Win8.1. I'm using that OS on my desktop right now. This used to work only as a double click on a title bar, which would maximize it.

Comment: @c00000fd: Double-clicking the bottom border of a window certainly does work on my Windows 8.1 installation.  There's something affecting it other than simply Windows version.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Hah, you're right. I just fired up a VM with 8.1 and sure enough it works there. So you're correct. Interesting. I don't know why it doesn't seem to work on my main Win 8.1 box. I don't have any shell extensions of any customizations there. So go figure... Maybe it's because I haven't rebooted it in a few months and something got goofed up...

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321549/handling-aerosnap-message-in-wndproc). AeroSnap was disabled on this rig as well, [this](https://superuser.com/a/860636/369805) helped to switch it back on.

Answer (score 1):

You are already handling `WM_NCHITTEST`.  Handle `WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK` and don't forward to `DefWindowProc` unless the hit test (in `wParam`) indicates the lower frame.

Comment: I tried. I even tried this, which does nothing to this resizing: `case WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK: {::SetWindowLongPtr(hDlg, DWLP_MSGRESULT, 0); return 1; }`. I'm guessing that this notification is sent after the fact. The only somewhat tedious "hack" that works is to manually override the window's size in `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`

Comment: @c00000fd: Well you could also try handling `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`... but I think your problem may be that you are using a dialog procedure and these messages are sent to the window procedure.  For dialog boxes, the system provides the window procedure --- but you can still subclass and override the handling.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: That's a value of zero (FALSE).  Return type from this message is just a true/false, not a hit detection zone.  My guess is that you did this in a proper window procedure and not a dialog proc?

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, that was for a window. In dialog it should return `TRUE` That works as expected as well (tested in Windows 10)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I tried it as well and it didn't. Mind to show your actual code?

Comment: You have `LRESULT` in what seems to be a dialog procedure, I am confused. Dialog procedure should be `INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgWndProc(...)` I tested `case WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK: return TRUE;` in a dialog procedure and it works.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Those are just remnants of my experimentations. So yes, it's a dialog procedure.

Answer (score 0):

here's the workaround that seems to work for me. It is not really about blocking the double-clicks. (Apart from subclassing the `WndProc` of a dialog box, which I haven't tried, I failed to block that double-click effect in `DlgProc` alone.) My workaround presented below is to achor the top of the popup window and let it drop down to the bottom of the screen, if the user who double-clicks the bottom border wants similar stuff to happen.

Since this does not answer my original question, I won't mark it as such.

```
//Add this case statement to my original code

case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
    {
        WINDOWPOS* pWP = (WINDOWPOS*)lParam;
        if(!(pWP->flags & (SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)))
        {
            int w = rcInitialWindowRectangle.right - rcInitialWindowRectangle.left;
            if(w > 0)
            {
                //Anchor the top of the popup window
                pWP->x = rcInitialWindowRectangle.left;
                pWP->y = rcInitialWindowRectangle.top;

                pWP->cx = w;

                int h = pWP->cy;

                //Make sure that the height fits the screen
                POINT pnt = {pWP->x, pWP->y};
                MONITORINFO mi = {0};
                mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
                if(::GetMonitorInfo(::MonitorFromPoint(pnt, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST), &mi))
                {
                    if(pWP->y + h > mi.rcWork.bottom)
                    {
                        int nMinDefaultH = rcInitialWindowRectangle.bottom - 
                            rcInitialWindowRectangle.top;

                        int nAh = mi.rcWork.bottom - y;
                        if(nAh >= nMinDefaultH)
                            h = nAh;
                        else
                            h = nMinDefaultH;
                    }
                }

                pWP->cy = h;
            }
        }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Interesting. The SO parser automatically removes `Guys,` part from the beginning of this message.